# order comments in pdf invoice

Tags: orders, magento-1, pdf

I have created an extension to modify invoice PDF, in that want to add order comments. I am extending 
`Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` and `Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php` files.
 What is the method to fetch order comments. I have tried the following method

```
 $commentHistory =  $order->getStatusHistoryCollection(true);
```

Please help.

Comment: You should be able to get comments from an order object by calling ->getAllStatusHistory()

Comment: @DouglasRadburn why not adding it as an answer?? It is quite an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all order comments from calling `->getAllStatusHistory()` - as long as you have an ordr object, try calling:

`$commentHistory =  $order->getAllStatusHistory(true);`

Then loop through the array you get back.

Comment: It worked well. Thank you so much Douglas Radburn.

Answer (score 2):

You can get All the order comments using the following:

```
<?php

    foreach ($orderDetails->getAllStatusHistory() as $orderComment){

        echo $comment = $orderComment->getComment();

} ?>
```